# How to manually remove several bookmarks that show up in search and can not be deleted

Tags: firefox, firefox-profile

I have several bookmarks in Firefox that return in search, are shown as starred, but do not exists.

I deleted ALL bookmarks, an these bookmarks still appear in search. They are dead links as well.

How do I delete these bookmarks, preferable without completely uninstalling Firefox.

After following answer by the Dr below, maybe what it broken is search and how could I fix search from showing bookmarks that no longer exist and have been deleted.

e.g. When I click star(bookmarks) "*This time, search with*", the **Bookmarks** search box appears in search bar and the deleted bookmarks are returned as results.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of these bookmarks?

Answer (score 0):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> (letter O) in *Firefox* to *Show All Bookmarks*.

[image: Firefox Library Dialog]

- Notice that there are *multiple* folders of Bookmarks; browse all for those to delete.
- You can *Search* Bookmarks for specific items.
- Also check *History*, to see if the location is stored there.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to disable add-on *Extensions* that might be inserting the Bookmark in your search.
- You can also use the free utility [Browser Addons View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_browser_addons_view.html) fro Nirsoft to see if some nefarious add-on has been installed to (mis)direct Search.
- If the link is from Mozilla, it might be stored in *about:config*, which can be searched, too.

Comment: Maybe a better question is how do I prevent search showing bookmarks that no longer exist and have been deleted.